# Why offset columns?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, offset

Why should one offset columns in bootstrap?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4">...</div>
    <div class="span3 offset2">...</div>
</div>
```

I know that we can move columns with offset property, but what is the use of it?

Could I see some examples, please? For instance, in this example

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem

in what way will arranging in columns help us out?

Comment: It's explained in the docs under "Offsetting Columns" http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem

Answer (score 0):

ok offset means to move colums right or left,
eg:
span3 offset2 means the gap between 2 colums is of 2 colums lenght
span3 offset1 means the gap between 2 colums is of 1 colums length

in bootstrap there are 12 colums, so minimum is width b/w 2 colums is 1 coumn.